# How to ask a question about why a product doesn't exist

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

So I understand questions that invite purely speculative answers are not helpful here. But I have a real use case situation and the fact that the product I'm looking for doesn't seem to exist both frustrates and perplexes me, and I'd love some help forming the right question to ask on the main site.

Text editors that can edit, display, and reshape data, code, and more freeform text have been a staple of just about every computer operating system. iPhones have more processing power than most computers I've used in my life, and iPads are being marketed as replacements for notebook-form computers. And yet whenever I have any serious text to edit, whether Perl or JavaScript or a big CSV file encoding an exam I'm writing for a class I'm teaching, I find myself firing up my Mac to do the editing, because nothing in iOS seems to be able to do the job of BBEdit. But I don't understand why that is. It would seem that by now there would be a great text editor for iOS. The fact that one hasn't emerged seems to suggest that there is some barrier to its existence.

I wouldn't think "why doesn't product X exist" would be on-topic here; it seems like all the answers would be speculative. Is there a good way to ask that? The lack of a solid text editor for iOS is a real source of frustration to me, and I'd love to figure out if one doesn't exist simply because someone hasn't gotten around to making one yet, or if there is some hardware or OS limitation that prevents this operating system from yielding its native version of one of the fundamental computer tools that almost every other computer environment seems to have evolved.

Does anyone know how to ask this in a way that would produce high-quality answers?

Comment: This OP did exactly that:  https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/267009/119271

Answer (score 3):

You might first post a question on [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com) (or, if applicable, [Hardware Recommendations](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/)) to ensure that no such product exists.

If no solution exists then you might ask *how* to do what you want on one of the SE developer forums as a way of eliciting obstacles.